# Cyclically call function based on segments of input

Tags: java, loops, iteration

I'm working on a class assignment.  I need to read in a file containing lines of input.  Every block of three lines is a structured set:  The first is one polynomial, the second is another polynomial, the third is a text string that indicates the algebraic operation for the polynomial arithmetic.  I've set my program up so that it reads each line into an array, and then I parse the two array indices containing integers into my polynomial term.  I call the appropriate function based on the third line.  My struggle is finding a way to get the process to reset after each third line.  Here is the code for my main function.  I thought I would use an i-loop (k-loop here) somehow, but I can't get it to work.  Any insight or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Example of input:

```
3 2 4 5

5 7 4 6

subtract

4 3 5 1

1 2 3 4

add
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Polynomial p1 = new Polynomial();
    Polynomial p2 = new Polynomial();
    int lines = 0;

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Test.txt"));

        String line=null;

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(line);
            lines++;
        } // end while
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("lines " + lines);

    for (int k=0; k<lines; k++){
        String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println(stringArr[k+0]);
        System.out.println(stringArr[k+1]);
        System.out.println(stringArr[k+2]);

        String[] nums1 = stringArr[k+0].split(" ");
        String[] nums2 = stringArr[k+1].split(" ");

        for (int i=0; i<nums1.length; i+= 2) {
            p1.addTerm(Integer.parseInt(nums1[i]), Integer.parseInt(nums1[i+1]));
        }
        for (int i=0; i<nums2.length; i+= 2) {
            p2.addTerm(Integer.parseInt(nums2[i]), Integer.parseInt(nums2[i+1]));
        }

        if (stringArr[k+2].equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {add(p1,p2);}
        else if (stringArr[k+2].equalsIgnoreCase("subtract")) {subtract(p1,p2);}
        else if(stringArr[k+2].equalsIgnoreCase("multiply")) {multiply(p1,p2);}
        else {
            System.out.println("Bad input");
        }
        nums1=null;
        nums2=null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Try something like the Scanner class? Catch the `NoSuchElementException` if it should run out of lines in the file.

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new String("input"));

 while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String lineOne = scanner.nextLine();
        String lineTwo = scanner.nextLine();
        String lineThree = scanner.nextLine();
        calculateSomething(lineOne, lineTwo, lineThree);
    }
```

It can be used to read strings to (space-delimited by default)

```
 private static int[] getPolynomialFactors(String line) {
    Scanner splitter = new Scanner(line);

    int[] p = new int[4];
    int counter=0;

    while (splitter.hasNextInt()){
        p[counter] = splitter.nextInt();
        counter++;
    }
    return  p;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm learning to read input from files, so tips concerning Scanner are extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With a good night's sleep, I was able to figure it out.  I used a for-loop and just had to modify the incrementing of the loop counter.  I nulled the pointers to the integer arrays I was using to store the integers parsed from the first two lines of the code block, which effectively reset them.  Here is my updated code that works:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Polynomial p1 = new Polynomial();
        Polynomial p2 = new Polynomial();
        int lines = 0;

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Test.txt"));

            String line=null;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(line);
                lines++;
            } // end while
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("lines " + lines);
        String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);


        for (int k=0; k<lines; k+=3){

            System.out.println(stringArr[k+0]);
            System.out.println(stringArr[k+1]);
            System.out.println(stringArr[k+2]);             


            String[] nums1 = stringArr[k+0].split(" ");
            String[] nums2 = stringArr[k+1].split(" ");

            for (int i=0; i<nums1.length; i+= 2) {
                p1.addTerm(Integer.parseInt(nums1[i]), Integer.parseInt(nums1[i+1]));
            }
            for (int i=0; i<nums2.length; i+= 2) {
                p2.addTerm(Integer.parseInt(nums2[i]), Integer.parseInt(nums2[i+1]));
            }

            if (stringArr[k+2].equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {add(p1,p2);}
            else if (stringArr[k+2].equalsIgnoreCase("subtract")) {subtract(p1,p2);}
            else if(stringArr[k+2].equalsIgnoreCase("multiply")) {multiply(p1,p2);}
            else {
                System.out.println("Bad input");
                break;
            }
            nums1=null;
            nums2=null;
        }
    }
}
```